# How do I fix my CPU fan on Ubuntu?

Tags: fan

I have an Acer laptop with only one fan and Ubuntu is not using it. lm-sensors is not giving me the rpm.I've tried with i8kutils with this config:

```
# Run as daemon, override with --daemon option
set config(daemon)      0

# Automatic fan control, override with --auto option
set config(auto)        1

# Report status on stdout, override with --verbose option
set config(verbose) 1

# Status check timeout (seconds), override with --timeout option
set config(timeout) 20

# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
set config(0)   {{-1 0}  -1  40  -1  40}
set config(1)   {{-1 1}  30  60  30  60}
set config(2)   {{-1 2}  50  100  50 100}

# For computer with 2 fans, use a variant of this instead:
# Temperature thresholds: {fan_speeds low_ac high_ac low_batt high_batt}
# set config(0) {{-1 0}  -1  52  -1  65}
# set config(1) {{-1 1}  41  66  55  75}
# set config(2) {{-1 1}  55  80  65  85}
# set config(3) {{-1 2}  70 128  75 128}

# end of file
```

This did not work! This is the output on i8kmon command:

```
reading system config file
i8kmon
config(0)          = {-1 0} -1 40 -1 40
config(1)          = {-1 1} 30 60 30 60
config(2)          = {-1 2} 50 100 50 100
config(3)          = {2 2} 70 128 75 128
config(acpi)       = acpi
config(auto)       = 1
config(daemon)     = 0
config(i8kfan)     = /usr/bin/i8kfan
config(sysconfig)  = /etc/i8kmon.conf
config(t_high)     = 80
config(timeout)    = 20
config(use_conf)   = 1
config(userconfig) = ~/.i8kmon
config(verbose)    = 1
status(ac)         = 0
status(acpi_timer) = 0
status(leftspeed)  = 0 -1 -1 -1
status(lspeed)     = 0
status(lstate)     = -2
status(lstuck)     = 0
status(nfans)      = 2
status(rightspeed) = 0 -1 -1 -1
status(rspeed)     = 0
status(rstate)     = -2
status(rstuck)     = 0
status(state)      = 0
status(t_high)     = 0
status(t_low)      = 0
status(temp)       = 0
/usr/bin/i8kfan -1 0
1597589318 acpi: Battery 0: Full, 100%
temp, left fan state, right fan state, ac state: -1 -1 -1 0
```

Comment: The laptop has to have the ability to read the speed in order for it to work, are you able to see the speed in Windows (if you dual boot)?  What is in `/proc/acpi/`?

Comment: I have a wakeup file and a button directory. On windows, the fan worked fine!

Comment: you can try to see if `sensors-detect` finds anything, but usually I don't see much luck with laptops.  If you have `/sys/devices/virtual/thermal` present, `thinkfan` might be the way to go.  i8kutils is usually for Dells.

Comment: actually looking at my laptop, I can't see the fan speeds, and looking at `/sys/devices/virtual/thermal/cooling_device*/*` it doesn't show them there either.

Comment: but can you hear or feel yours? mine is not blowing any air, hot or cold. my laptop is getting hot but the fun is not pushing out.

Comment: I think the bios controls the fans in mine.  I can see acpi_thermal_pm running but I can't kill it to see if it breaks the fan control.  Running `stress -c 8` will get it nice and hot so the fans turn on after a few seconds.